# Unable to install php5-fpm on ubuntu 16.04 digital ocean droplet

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, fpm

I am trying to setup phppgadmin and it requires php5-fpm but as I have ubuntu 16.04 and it comes with php 7. So when i try to run install php5-fpm it give me following error:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm

Package php5-fpm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'php5-fpm' has no installation candidate
```

I can't use php7-fpm as phppgadmin requires only php5-fpm. When I run sudo apt-get install php-fpm it installed php7-fpm . I am using nginx as web server. I tried many ppa but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR: If you want to stay with php5, you will need to stay at Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

You can use [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) to install older/different php-version, that are not part of the actual package-repositories of ubutu.
phpbrew builds and installs multiple version php(s) in your $HOME directory.

Another way is to modify the `sources.list` and a repository which still provides php5 packages. **But you really should not do that!**

Comment: can I install php5-fpm with php7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a PPA to do this. Consider:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6
```

That's PHP5.6, not exactly PHP5-FPM. I don't think FPM is in that PPA but it's a close enough solution. Maybe you can find an FPM PPA but I'm not seeing one at first glance.